# when i use the magnification api, i get a linker error?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, magnification

Here is my code I got this from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/magapi/magapi-intro

```
#include <iostream>
#include<magnification.h>

BOOL SetZoom(float magnificationFactor)
{
    // A magnification factor less than 1.0 is not valid.
    if (magnificationFactor < 1.0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Calculate offsets such that the center of the magnified screen content 
    // is at the center of the screen. The offsets are relative to the 
    // unmagnified screen content.
    int xDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(
        SM_CXSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);
    int yDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(
        SM_CYSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);

    return MagSetFullscreenTransform(magnificationFactor, xDlg, yDlg);
}

int main()
{
}
```

When I try to run this, I get a linking error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol MagSetFullscreenTransform referenced in function "int __cdecl SetZoom(float)" (?SetZoom@@YAHM@Z) coolymagnify    C:\Users\antso_jrb0i02\Documents\programming\coolymagnify\coolymagnify\coolymagnify.obj 1

I tried finding a solution, but I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: It looks like you should *link* the library for [the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetfullscreentransform) (`Magnification.lib` or something).

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that all you have to do to use a third party library functions is include the header file. This generally works for functions in the standard library but not usually for third party libraries. You must also link with whatever library it is that provides that function.

Comment: @hhh Per the same documentation you linked to in your question: "*Support for the Magnification API is provided by Magnification.dll. **To compile your application, include Magnification.h and link to Magnification.lib**.*"